# Issue when Implementing gradient descent in R

Tags: r

I have problems implementing a gradient descent in R for an exponential function.

Let's say

```
foo <- function(x) {
  y = -2 + 2.5 * exp(0.1*x^2-0.7*x)
  return(y) }
```

is my exponential function then

```
 grad <- function(x) {
     y = 2.5*exp(0.1*x^2-0.7*x)*(0.2*x-0.7)
     return(y) }
```

is the gradient function of foo(x).

The task is to implement a function called

```
gdescent <- function(x0, fc, grd, diff, step) {}
```

where

- x0 is a random initial value
- foo is the exponential function I want to minimize
- grad is the gradient function (derivative of foo(x))
- diff is the difference that terminates the algo
- step is the size of the steps (i.e. the learning rate)

The result of the function shall be a list containing

- *par* - the value of x in the minimum;
- *value* - the corresponding value of foo(par) at the minimum;
- and *iter* - the number of iterations it took the algo to find the minimum.

The update rule after every iteration shall be:

```
xi+1 = xi - step * grd(xi) # i didn't understand this at all
```

How do I implement this in R?

My understanding of the gradient descent method so far:

1. pick a random initial value x0 insert x0 in the gradient function grd(x)
2. if grd(x0) < 0, reduce x0 by "step" (x0+1=x0-step);
3. if grd(x0) > 0, increase x0 by "step" (x0+1=x0+step); and go back to 2) with x0+1 as initial value

my solution so far:

```
gdescent <- function(x0, fc, grd, diff, step) {
x = x0
x_history = vector("numeric", iter)    
for(i in 1:iter) {
   x = x - step * grad(x)
   if( x > diff ) {                 #not sure how to proceed here
  }                                 
}
```

How can I solve this without a fixed number of iterations? so without initialising iter

Comment: For a theoretical understanding of the update rule, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). For a practical implementation, please choose a function.

Comment: What part didn't you understand? Gradient descent or how to implement it in R? Also, are you aiming for stochastic GD or the basic one? The usual GD has a very simple formula (you've written it above) and it should stop once the gradient equals to zero. The SGD never reaches this point, hence it will need some tolerance. In either way, this question is too broad. This isn't Corusera here.You need to decide exactly what you need, try achieving it yourself, in case of failure, provide a **minimal & reproducible** example of the problem.